# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dC}{dt} = -\alpha C$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> After drinking a cup of coffee, the amount $C$ of caffeine in a person's
>   body obeys the differential equation
>
> $$\frac{dC}{dt} = -\alpha C$$
>   where the constant $-\alpha$ has an approximate value of $0.14$ hours$^{{−1}}$.
>
> How many hours will it take a human body to metabolize half of the
>   initial amount of caffeine? Round your answer to the nearest integer.

Firstly, I am having a little trouble understanding the question. Is the question asking for $c(t)$? Next, I tried the following approach

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dC}{dt} &= -\alpha C\\
\int \frac{dC}{C} &= \int -\alpha dt \\
C &= \exp (-\alpha t + c)\\
C &= e^{-\alpha t} + e^c \\
\end{align}$$

That is where I am stuck. It is asking "half of the initial amount of caffeine" which means that $e^{c}$ is $e^\frac{1}{2}$ because $c$ is my initial amount. So then what do I do next? make $C = 0$? Please don't provide me with the full answer, just some hints.

Thanks!

Comment: The last line is wrong. It should be $C=e^ce^{-\alpha t}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh right! Because the general solution is of that form but how can I proceed from there?

Comment: I guess we can assume that the caffeine is absorbed immediately, so the caffeine at $t=0$ is, as @André pointed out, $e^c e^0 = e^c$. So, for what $t$ do we get half of that?

Comment: @gekkostate: It is not quite because the general solution is of that form. It is because $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$, and **not** $e^x+e^y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There was an algebra glitch, you should have
$$C(t)=e^c e^{-\alpha t}.$$
Put $t=0$. We get $e^c=C(0)$, so
$$C(t)=C(0)e^{-\alpha t}.$$
Continue.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused - a little. Now that we have that equation, we are looking for $t$. So does that mean we set $C(t)$ to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Not exactly, but close. You set $C(t)=\frac{1}{2}C(0)$. Happily the $C(0)$ cancels. (Good thing, since we don't know it.). It's like all the other half-life stuff.